# Django REST framework inconsistent data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I request my user data from localhost:8000/users, I get users that look like this:

```
{
    "username": "iv4ha05k",
    "email": "xxxx@xxx.com",
    "profile": {
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/images-4.jpg"
    },
    "pk": 303
},
```

But, if I request user data from the django manage shell, the data will look like this:

```
{
    "username": "iv4ha05k",
    "email": "xxxx@xxx.com",
    "profile": {
        "image": "/media/images-4.jpg"
    },
    "pk": 303
},
```

Notice how the image url becomes truncated. I am querying the same exact database in the same exact state, and it has nothing to do with migrations or anything of the like. I discovered this issue when trying to write custom API views. When I would query the User viewset, it would return data with the full image address. But, when I try to write a custom API view that queries the user database, it will return it with the truncated address. I am using django's `FileSystemStorage`, if that helps anyone.. Thanks.

Comment: '/media/images-4.jpg' is what is stored in the database as the url and that is what the shell will show you. Your serializer should expand this to the full media url.

Comment: I thought that this was the case originally, but even using the serializer it comes out the same way. Even if I get a user object and serialize just its profile, (an AutoOneToOne field), its still giving me the same result.

Comment: Scott, how would the shell know what the base url /hostname is?  There isn't a django server bound to a port and the requests don't tell django what the server name is, because there isn't a server in shell mode, really.  Furthermore, you can expose the _exact_ same code base through apache on multiple addresses and each REST interface will have a different base URL.  All that aside, how is this discrepancy currently hindering you?

Comment: Like I said, when I'm trying to create API views (instead of viewsets), the queries I use on the User table dont return the full address. But it returns the whole address when I use the viewset. I only included the comment about the management shell to possibly narrow down where to look for the issue, but I understand what you are saying. The issue actually has nothing to do with what the view is returning in the shell